# Windows 10 pro official installation media

Tags: windows-installation, windows-10-pro

I have a DELL laptop with windows home on it. (sticker license).
I want to download windows 10 pro and install it on this laptop.
So I downloaded from here the media creation tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

After the installation, I saw that it is windows home.
Nothing about home or pro was mentioned during the installation...
Where can I download windows 10 pro to install on my dell laptop?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Windows 10 installer from using the preinstalled serial key without disabling UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa)

Comment: You will either have to use a valid Windows 10 Professional key or use the generic Windows 10 Professional license key and then supply a valid key after Windows 10 Professional is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1200162/clean-install-windows-10-and-then-using-windows-7-8-1-serial/1200164#1200164 and https://superuser.com/questions/1004242/are-the-installation-media-for-windows-10-home-and-professional-different/1120634#1120634 and https://superuser.com/questions/1118592/how-do-i-activate-windows-10-pro-on-a-laptop-that-came-with-windows-10-home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/948303/does-the-windows-10-iso-have-a-ei-cfg-file-for-changing-the-edition/948779#948779).  This particular duplicate tells you exactly what to do. You can also just delete the PID.txt and ei.cfg files if you want and all editions on the ISO will be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings, Update and Security, and Activation. Select Change Product key and enter your Windows 10 Pro product key. It should process the update to Windows 10 Pro.